# Using angularjs.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped nuget package not working

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio, typescript, nuget

**Scenario:**

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 with TypeScript installed.

I created a `'HTML Application with TypeScript'` project and I installed all those packages:

`package.config` file:

```
<package id="angularjs" version="1.6.1" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="angularjs.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped" version="6.5.6" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="bootstrap" version="3.3.7" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="jQuery" version="1.9.1" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="jquery.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped" version="3.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
```

**Problem:**

In my `app.ts` file I typed:

```
declare var jQuery: JQueryStatic;
declare var angular: angular.IAngularStatic;
...
```

But I keep getting the error:

> Cannot find namespace 'angular'.

How can I fix that?
Or how can I use angular in typescript files in a visual studio project?

**Edited**

PS: All packages was installed by nuget and in Visual Studio running as Administrator mode.

Comment: Try to open visual studio in administrator mode and install it via NuGet.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I already try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fix the problem adding `reference path` command to app.ts file:

`app.ts` file

```
/// <reference path="Scripts/typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="Scripts/typings/angularjs/angular.d.ts" />

declare var jQuery: JQueryStatic;
declare var angular: angular.IAngularStatic;

(() => {

    var app = angular.module("myapp", []);

})();
```

Comment: Glad to know that you have resolved this issue. Please mark your answer which is benefit to other communities who has the same problem.